# Velocity of efflux by method of forces

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I've been trying to derive the Torricelli's law by using Newton's first and second law but I'm not coming up with an exact answer. Here's the problem.

Consider a large cylindrical vessel with a very small orifice of surface area $S$ at the bottommost circular surface. We want to find the velocity of the water coming out of the orifice ,if water is filled to a height $h$ above the bottommost surface.

I chose the system to be the whole liquid minus a small fraction of liquid just above the orifice. Since the container has a vey large area as compared to the orifice , liquid must have negligible velocity and near to zero accelaration . Therefore by using Newton's first law of motion , the net forces on the system must be zero.
The system is acted upon by atmospheric pressure, gravity, and the forces due to the container. If the liquid is approximately at rest then the normal forces must exactly balance the weight of liquid on all regions except the one just above the orifice ; the unbalanced force being equal to ${\rho}Shg$.

The small cup just above the orifice is ejected with a velocity $V_{rel}$ and exerts a thrust force ${\rho}SV_{rel}^2$.
Hence applying the condition for equilibrium we get :

$${\rho}Shg={\rho}SV_{rel}^2$$
Or
$$V_{rel}={\sqrt{hg}}$$
Am I wrong with elementary concepts or concepts of fluid mechanics?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a balance between potential and kinetic energy, your 'thrust force' in this case is missing a factor $0.5$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: kinetic energy per unit volume is defined as $\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$ not $\rho v^2$

Comment: But that's not the thrust it imparts. Thrust is defined to be $dm/dt V_rel^2$. It turns out to be ${\rho}v^2$.

Comment: The forces by the other parts of the vessel wall are not quite hydrostatic when the fluid is flowing out, and the direction of the velocity vector near the orifice is not vertical.  The flow streamlines in the tank near the orifice are converging radially (in a hemispherical sense) toward the orifice.  So the basic premise of the analysis is not quite correct.

Comment: Thank you sir for providing such a wonderful insight . But how do I go about solving this problem . Are there any resources which I can refer ?

Comment: Newton's second law for an inviscid fluid is Euler's equation (a differential version of Newton's second law).  If Euler's equation is dotted with the velocity vector, one obtains the Bernoulli equation.  So the Bernoulli equation is actually a simplified version of Newton's second law that is applicable for problems like this.  So, for an inviscid fluid, using the Bernoulli equation is equivalent to using Newton's second law.

Comment: Of course, you can also solve Euler's equation in cylindrical coordinates for the velocity distribution in the tank and at the exit.  This will also give you the detailed pressure variations throughout the fluid, and the detailed force distribution on the walls.  So it will give you everything that you are trying to find in detail.  But, as far as the outlet velocity is concerned, it will give you the same outlet flow as the Bernoulli equation.

Comment: Does that mean that the only alternative I'm left with is to apply Bernoulli's equation ( which is possibly a form a Newton's second law)?( I'm a high school student familiar only with the basics of physics )

Comment: Well, the Bernoulli equation is just a form of the equation for conservation of mechanical energy, and should be pretty easy to use even for a high school student.  Google it, and see what you think.